# php stmt similar products display

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP stmt similar products display script this script working but not showing similar products I want to display similar products title

Here is my code

```
<?php 
$id=$row['id'];
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title
FROM products order by rand() limit 3
")){
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    //results
}}
?>
```

view.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    include("config.php");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from products where id = '$id'";
         $result = $con->query($sql); 
           if($result->num_rows > 0){           
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    //results
              }}}
           ?>
```

Comment: What is a 'similar product'? One with an ID near the ID of the searched product? One that has the same 'name'? One that has the same 'category'? We can't possibly know how to craft your query to find a similar product without knowing what a similar product *is* (and you also listing your table structure) -- sample data would help too.

Comment: there are two table category and products

Comment: I saw that same question yesterday. With very similar comments. What has changed in the past 24 hours?

Comment: You're not using the $id variable anywhere? What does your table look like and what do you want to get from it?

Comment: I want to get similar title from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that Database credentials were okay.

Try the code below and let me know

**1) Query using rand() method( This is what you want)**

```
<?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = 'your password goes here';
         $dbname = 'your database goes here';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
         $sql = 'SELECT title FROM products order by rand() limit 3';
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```

**2.) Query Using where Clause in this case an id(1) to show product title where id of 1 matches it in the database**

```
<?php


         $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = 'your password goes here';
         $dbname = 'your database goes here';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
         $sql = "SELECT id,title FROM products where id='1'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```

**Updated Section**

First create table below and insert into it

```
create table products(id int(11) primary key auto_increment,title varchar(30),description varchar(30),image varchar(30),cat_id int(11));
```

You will insert at least one record

```
insert into products (id,title,description,image,cat_id) values(1,'product title','product details','product.png',100);
```

For testing query the products table to get details where **id is 1**

```
<?php

         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'anglejs';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
         $sql = "SELECT id,title,description,image,cat_id FROM products where id='1'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
               echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
                 echo "description: " . $row["description"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```

Now since the Id is coming from **url**

**For testing purpose:**

You can save the code as **view.php** like you did
Open your browser and Enter something like

**http://localhost/-----yourfolder diretory goes here-----/view.php?id=1**
You can see **Id of 1** coming from the Url as appended to view.php files. since we have inserted record which has id of 1, the code below will display the
records only for rows where **id is = 1** and so on....

```
<?php

         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'anglejs';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';


$id = $_GET['id'];
//check if id is empty
if($id==''){
echo "Id is empty";
exit;
}

         $sql = "SELECT id,title,description,image,cat_id FROM products where id='$id'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
               echo "Title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
                 echo "description: " . $row["description"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```

Comment: I added this code working but not showing same title

Comment: what do you mean by the same title. are you looking for a particular title or what. You are using rand() function which means telling the database to pick title randomly. if you want the same title then remove rand() from the sql queries. use this $sql = 'SELECT title FROM products';

Comment: I added not changing products

Comment: Previn. it seems that you are confused. First you said the code is working but not showing the same title. Now I ask you to remove Rand() function and you are now telling me that the product is not changing. Please update your post. send me all your code

Comment: Again. You can also decide how your record will be displayed using ASC or DESC method. If your table product has productid as may be primarykey.  Eg. $sql = 'SELECT title FROM products order by productId asc';  or  $sql = 'SELECT title FROM products order by productId desc';

Comment: I added products view file

Comment: two question what table rows are you displaying here  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    //results
              }

Comment: this file is view products

Comment: why are you commenting the result rows. I need to see what rows that you want to echo

Comment: since you are hurlding your code. there is nothing else I can do for you. asking you for the last time what is here that you commented  //results

Comment: I  cant understand brother I want to display related products please help me

Comment: can I see your table for Products.  I mean sample of how u created your table so that I can know all the column names

Comment: id,title,description,image,cat_id

Comment: I guess your id is int and primary key right. am working on it and in less than 5 minutes you will get reply so stay tight

Comment: See Updated section of my answer. I have tested the code and both code is working for me. I created table and insert into it . I provided two sample. make sure to change database credentials to suit yours.

Comment: @previn, have you tested the code.  is there any issue again

Comment: thank you this code working good I want to display random similar products

Comment: You should have know this by now that to display random records you should use rand() method. I have explain this many time
in my answer and in the comment. please see example below which makes random selection and limit products display to 9 items 


$sql = "SELECT id,title,description,image,cat_id FROM products order by rand() limit 9";

Comment: I will also appreciate if you can upvote my answers. Thanks you Mr. Previn